# Combining two complex meshes

Tags: mesh

So I have two photoscans that I want to create one single mesh out of.

Here's my usual method: I would use a shrinkwrap (sometimes even one made from the orignal models) to wrap around each model with the help of vertex groups. Then I may use remesh and sculpting to fix artifacts, then shrinkwrapping again to get an even nicer mesh (it sounds like I'm going backwards but it works because the remeshed mesh can be messy in spots). Lastly I would bake out the textures from each model and blend them each into eachother in photoshop.

Is there a better way of doing this?

[image: The two halves]

Comment: Can you move one of the objects to the side and take a screenshot so I can see how they look?

Comment: Trying to figure out the two meshes, but currently it looks like the 2nd mesh is pretty much just the skull missing the scalp & lower ends of the teeth. If that's the case, and assuming the 2nd skull is the mesh details needed for the face and you're just adding in the scalp and teeth from the 1st mesh, I'd cut out the face on the full 1st skull, merge it with the 2nd mesh, and then use Bridge Edge Loops to merge the gaps. Maybe go in afterwards again and just retopo/sculpt on those edges then to fix them, rather than trying to fix the whole mesh.

Comment: Sorry this isn't the best way to show both meshes it was a bit silly of me! Here's a better picture: http://i.imgur.com/34idlPu.png?1 Also I like that idea VolkEnVanderland, not to mention I could use retopoflow. Thanks, will try that to start with